# Salvando vários array de uma vez laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom tenho uma função que é complexa, pois preciso dentro de uma mesma função fazer vários `for` devido a complexidade e a quantidade de informação.

Estou consumindo uma API onde preciso pegar dados mensais de determinada pessoa, e a cada dia pode ter varios items, ou seja trocando em miudos.

```
Pessoa 01
    MES 01
        PRODUTO 01
        PRODUTO 02
    MES 02
        PRODUTO 01
    MES 03
        PRODUTO 01
        PRODUTO 02
        PRODUTO 03
    MES 04
```

Assim tenho que percorre cada dado e salvando um por um.
Minha função desenvolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
$todosMembros = DB::select('select id from membros');

    foreach ($todosMembros as $membro){
        for($a = 1; $a < 13; $a++){ //AQUI preciso ir pois é mensal então tenho 12 messes
            $categorias = meuAPI; //AQUI preciso ir uma vez para cada membro
            $json_file = file_get_contents($categorias);
            $json_str = json_decode($json_file);
            $todasCategorias = $json_str->list;

            $tamanho = count($todasCategorias);

            if($tamanho == 0){//CASO Não haja dados para ele não faço nada

            }else{
                $tamnhoArray = count($todasCategorias); //QUANTIDADE DE PRODUTOS

                for($w = 0; $w < $tamnhoArray; $w++){ //PARA CADA PRODUTO SALVO NO BANCO
                    DB::select('salvar dados');//AQUI EFETIVO O SALVAMENTO
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Meu problema é que esta salvando porém estou excedendo o tempo de espera do navegador, ou seja demoro tanto nos loops da função que o tempo limite é excedido, verifiquei no banco de dado e esta salvando normalmente, após salvar tudo eu listo para verificar se ocorreu tudo certinho, porém não aparece nada justamente pelo limite.

A minha questão é: 
Qual a melhor maneira de efetivar este dados no banco de dados, para não gerar problemas para minha aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### set_time_limit

Normalmente isso acontece por causa do timeout do php, tenta definir o max execution time para um valor maior, ou zero para desabilitar e nao parar ate acabar a execucao do script.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

As vezes da time out simplesmente por que o servidor nao retornou nenhum dado, nesse caso poderia usar os `ob_flush()`, assim o navegador vai saber que teve resposta e não vai dar timeout.

#### ob_flush()

Conforme você vai exibindo conteudo, normalmente chamando `echo`, `var_dump()`, `print()`, e derivados, tudo isso vai sendo armazenado em um buffer, assim que o buffer atinge o o tamanho limite ele despeja `flush()` esse conteudo para o navegador. O `ob_flush()` serve para "forçar" esse despejo, logo o conteudo aparece na hora.

Se você colocar um echo no final do ultimo for

```
for($w = 0; $w < $tamnhoArray; $w++){ //PARA CADA PRODUTO SALVO NO BANCO
    DB::select('salvar dados');//AQUI EFETIVO O SALVAMENTO
    echo "Dados foram salvos<br>";
 }
```

vai perceber que vai demorar um pouco para comecar a aparecer os textos, e quando aparecer vai aparecer varias linhas de uma vez, isso por que tava tudo no buffer.

Se adicionar o `ob_flush()`depois do `echo` voce vai ver que o texto vai ser exibido linha a linha.

```
for($w = 0; $w < $tamnhoArray; $w++){ //PARA CADA PRODUTO SALVO NO BANCO
    DB::select('salvar dados');//AQUI EFETIVO O SALVAMENTO
    echo "Dados foram salvos<br>";
    ob_flush();
 }
```

O que acontece é que quando quando chamar o `echo` o texto fica no buffer, logo em seguida o `ob_flush()` força o despejo para o navegador, como a unica coisa no buffer era o texto do `echo` ele é exibido na hora.

Comment: Como utilizar o `ob_flush()` ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues editei a resposta e adicionei uma explicação do ob_flush()